# print correctly a query in sqllite android

Tags: android, sqlite, println

I have the following table scheme

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
// To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
// give it an empty constructor.
public FeedReaderContract() {
}

/* Inner class that defines the table contents */
public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
}
```

}

and I initialize the table with the following function

```
public void put_info(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    int id = 999;
    String title = "Sophia";
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, id);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);

    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            values);

}
```

I try to make a request like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                    // don't filter by row groups
            sortOrder                                 // The sort order
    );
```

where

```
        String[] projection = {
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID,
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE,
    };
```

then I try to print the query in the following way:

```
        String result = "";

    int iRow = cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID);
    int iName = cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE);
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result = result + cursor.getString(iRow) + " " + cursor.getString(iName) + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

My problem is that I get a strange output like

```
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 1 title
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 2 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 3 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 4 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 5 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 6 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 7 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 8 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 9 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 10 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 11 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 12 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 13 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 14 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 15 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 16 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 17 Sophia
10-05 03:04:55.005 19717-19717/com.mycompany.antibes I/System.out: 18 Sophia
```

while I would like my output to be something like:

```
title 
999
sophia
```

That's also what I would expect from my query, since my database is done
of only one row and the request should give me back all the rows
(because the argument where I select the rows is null).

I don't understand as well the series of numbers from 1 to 18 in the output, I don't see any way in the code where this can come from.
Any ideas?

Comment: for debug purposes use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor`

Comment: Where does `iRow` come from?

Comment: could you give me a good reference to it? I don't find a lot on the web

Comment: @CL. sorry I forgot to add two important lines in my question, now I have edited the question and you can see iRow

Comment: @pskink if I understand correctly, I should output the cursor to a log file with something like public static void dumpCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        dumpCursor(cursor, System.out);
    } is it correct? which information I can get from it? how can it be useful in my case? I already have a print of the content of the cursor...

Comment: just call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor)`, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, id);
...
int iRow = cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID);
```

This is a different column.
(It is not a good idea to have two different keys. You probably want to drop `entryid` and to use `_id` instead.)

You get seventeen Sophias because you called `put_info()` seventeen times.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I call put_info() at the creation of my app. So I would like the database to be new each time I call the app.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I understood a bit the problem. The fact is that each time I start the app again, the result of the query will have a line more.
This means that my database is kept in the memory and not destroyed after each launch to the app. So now my question is how to create a new database at each run of the app. Where should I modify my code?

Comment: The whole point of a database is to keep your data. And to ask a question. use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @CL. ok so only if I reinstall my app a new database will be created, otherwise it will be kept in memory after each restart. thanks :)